# Woocommerce Onepage checkout does not show shipping costs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce One Page Checkout website with currently one product. Everything is working so far but for some reason I don't see the shippingcosts displayed.

The price calculcation is correct and when I go to the paymentportal the shippingcosts are added to the total price but the shipping costs are not displayed.

To give some insight in my search for the solution:
Rendering all the data happens in **/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php**

There is called:

```
<?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
```

This function can be found in **/woocommcerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php**

There the code being executed is:

```
/**
 * Get shipping methods
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
function wc_custom_cart_totals_shipping_html() {

    $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
    foreach ( $packages as $i => $package ) {
        $chosen_method = isset( WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $i ] ) ? WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $i ] : '';

        wc_get_template( 'cart/cart-shipping.php', array( 'package' => $package, 'available_methods' => $package['rates'], 'show_package_details' => ( sizeof( $packages ) > 1 ), 'index' => $i, 'chosen_method' => $chosen_method ) );
    }
}
```

The problem is that `$packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();`
returns an empty array.

The function get_packages in **/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shipping.php** is as follows:

```
/**
     * Get packages
     * @return array
     */
    public  function get_packages() {
        return $this->packages;
    }
```

So property $this->packages is not set. This property is set in function calculate_shipping in the same file **/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shipping.php**

I tried calling that function right before `$packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();` but that did not work.

Is there someone who can help me out? Please note that I don't have much experience in programming in Wordpress.

Kind regards,

Pim

Comment: If you purchased one page checkout you should contact Woo Support. This is a premium plugin that the majority of SO users won't have access to. Though I can tell you that first they will ask you to test against a default theme. If it works then you know the issue is with your theme's modifications of WooCommerce. And if the problem is with your theme you should contact your theme author. If the problem persists even with a default theme and other plugins disabled, then it may be a bug in OPC and the authors will want to fix it.

Comment: +1 to @helgatheviking's suggestion. In WooCommerce that method is called in WC_Cart if any of the following are true `is_checkout() || is_cart() || defined('WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT') || defined('WOOCOMMERCE_CART')` so I would suspect something in your theme or a bug in One Page Checkout.

Comment: Thnx for the hints, for now we have solved it in the easy way just by putting a text message that says that shipping costs are calculated on top of the displayed price. Thnx!

Answer (score 15):

Had the same issue but managed to figure it out after a while, you need to call

```
WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
```

This will populate the packages and then you can use

```
wc_cart_totals_shipping_html();
```

To show a list of the available shipping methods wherever you like

Comment: Thanks. Save my day ;)

Comment: Thank you very much!